# Send email on android application

Tags: android, sendmail

I am currently working on an Android application which has an "ask a question form", where user type a question and send it to predetermined email address. I would like to know how I can allow the application to capture what the user has input and send the input directly to a predeteremined email using button, either without bringing the user to the email app page, or capture all user input and send it to the built in email intent. I have seen many question related to my question but I just want to confirm that if I follow this [Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)

answer,  would it allow me to capture user input and send it to pre determined email address?

Following is the code I tried

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    convertEditTextVarsIntoStringsAndYesThisIsAMethodWeCreated();
    String[] to = {"someone@hotmail.co.uk"};

    String message[] = {name} ;
    String message2 [] = {mobile} ;
    String message3 [] = {email2} ;
    String message4 [] = {question} ;


    Intent Emailintent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND) ;
    Emailintent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);

    Emailintent.setType("plain/text");
    Emailintent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
    Emailintent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message2);
    Emailintent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message3);
    Emailintent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message4);
    startActivity(Emailintent);
}
private void convertEditTextVarsIntoStringsAndYesThisIsAMethodWeCreated() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    email2= youremail.getText().toString();
    mobile = yourmobile.getText().toString();
    name = yourname.getText().toString();
    question = yourquestion.getText().toString();


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, 
I think this is what you expecting, it will post all the details to your email box,

**Step 1:**

Call this `convertEditTextVarsIntoStringsAndYesThisIsAMethodWeCreated()` before sending your email.

(or)

**Step 2:
Use this Code**

In OnClick method

```
        convertEditTextVarsIntoStringsAndYesThisIsAMethodWeCreated();

        String body = "Name:"+ name+"\n Mobile"+ mobile+"\n Emailto"+email2+"\nQuestion"+ question;
        Intent emailtosend = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailtosend.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ to}); 
        emailtosend.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);

        //need this to prompts email client only
        emailtosend.setType("message/rfc822"); 

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailtosend, "Select email application"));
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank for your reply, but this code does not capture user input from my application's question form, it captures predetermined subject and body and put it into the builtin email's subject and body, I want to put user's input in the body. Can you help me with how to do that, look at the code I tried

Comment: no this wont capture you have to assign it to the form see my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
EditText ed=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
```

And when user edits the edit text, he presses a button:

```
button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Implement the onclick listener and add unimplemented methods and inside the onclicklistener, do the following:

```
String emailaddress="someone@yahoo.com";
String subject="Subject";
String message=ed.getText().toString();
Intent email = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailaddress);
email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
email.setType("plain/text");
email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
startActivity(email);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I tried it but it does not capture userinput and put text in the compose email box, here is my code:

Comment: Read the edit above.
P.S: If you're new to Android, its okay to mention it. It lets the answerer assess how detailed the answer should be.

Comment: Thanks a lot, its works. just had to change this String emailaddress="someone@yahoo.com"; to this,  String[] to = {"someone@hotmail.co.uk"};

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a) you gave,  it seems to work.
Keep in mind that, there is hard-coded password in the code.

Comment: does it allow sending mail to predetermined email address, and what do you mean by hard coded password?

Comment: @user1219484, yes it aloows. look at the code given in that answer. you will need a gmail username/password.                   sender.sendMail("This is Subject",   "This is Body", "user@gmail.com",   "user@yahoo.com");